# Unable to access Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In this code block, I want to capture SMS and calls to the user, but `Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE` is not accessible. How can I solve my problem?

```
// We define a BroadcastReceiver class that controls the flash when an SMS or a call arrives
class FlashReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

// We override the onReceive function inherited from the BroadcastReceiver class
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    // We get the action of the incoming intent
    val action = intent.action
    // If the action is SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION, it means an SMS has arrived
    if (action == Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) {
        // We call the flash function with the true parameter to flash the flash when an SMS arrives
        flash(context, true)

    // If the action is ACTION_PHONE_STATE, it means the call state has changed
    } else if (action == Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE) {

        // We get the call state from the intent
        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        // If the call state is RINGING, it means a call has arrived
        if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) {
            // We call the flash function with the true parameter to flash the flash when a call arrives
            flash(context, true)
        // If the call state is IDLE, it means the call has ended
        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) {
            // We call the flash function with the false parameter to turn off the flash when the call ends
            flash(context, false)
        }
    }
}

// We define a function that turns the flash on and off
private fun flash(context: Context, on: Boolean) {
    // We get the camera service
    val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    // We get the first camera ID
    val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
    // We set the flash mode according to the on parameter
    cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, on)
}

}
```

In our manifest file, we defined the camera, flash and phone features and permissions:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

In this code block, I want to capture SMS and calls to the user, but Intent.ACTION_PHONE_STATE is not accessible. How can I solve my problem?